# User's Outlook 2007 data files randomly removed

Tags: outlook, outlook-2007, exchange-server-2007, pst, data-files

Within our network infrastructure we utilize a 2007 Exchange Server for our domain.

Today I was faced with a situation where a user who has MS Office 2010 x64 and utilized Outlook 2010 called me and stated that her "Saved Items" inbox was missing. I remoted into her system and sure enough one of her mailboxes was not present.

It's easy enough to "fix" this by just adding the data file again which is located on a network share F:..\mailxxx.pst

This user has multiple mailboxes as a way to view her archived data.

Located in this shared folder there are additional .pst files that remained accessible to the user.

This appears to happen randomly and has happened at least one other time to this same user, and one time to a separate user who also has data on this same share.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft does not support PST files on a network drive. This is a recipe for a disaster.

Comment: Thank you, 


Since you've posted this I've read more about this unsupported environment on Microsoft's Technet blogs.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2007/01/21/network-stored-pst-files-dont-do-it/


Luckily for us we will be transitioning to Office 365 next week and this should not be an issue going forward.